# How could I print a @slice array elements in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, slice

I have this part of code to catch the greater value of an array immersed in a Hash. When Perl identified the biggest value the array is removed by @slice array:

```
if ( max(map $_->[1], @$val)){
my @slice = (@$val[1]);             
my @ignored = @slice;
delete(@$val[1]);
print "$key\t @ignored\n";
warn Dumper \@slice;
```

}

Data:Dumper out:

`$VAR1 = [ 
          [
            '3420',
            '3446',
            '13',
            '39',
            55
          ]
        ];`

I want to print those information separated by tabs (\t) in one line like this list:

```
miRNA127 dvex589433 -    131     154
miRNA154 dvex546562 +    232     259    
miRNA154 dvex573491 +    297     324    
miRNA154 dvex648254 +    147     172
miRNA154 dvex648254 +    287     272
miRNA32 dvex320240 -     61  83
miRNA32 dvex623745 -     141     163
miRNA79 dvex219016 +     ARRAY(0x100840378)
```

But in the last line always obtain this result.

How could I generate this output?:

```
miRNA127 dvex589433 -    131     154
miRNA154 dvex546562 +    232     259    
miRNA154 dvex573491 +    297     324    
miRNA154 dvex648254 +    147     172
miRNA154 dvex648254 +    287     272
miRNA32 dvex320240 -     61  83
miRNA32 dvex623745 -     141     163
miRNA79 dvex219016 +     3420    3446
```

Additional explication:
In this case, I want to catch the highest value in $VAR->[1] and looking if the subtraction with the minimum in $VAR->[0] is <= to 55. If not, i need to eliminate this AoA (the highest value) and fill a @ignored array with it. Next, i want to print some values of @ignored, like a list. Next, with the resultants AoA, I want to iterate the last flow...

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you say it does. `max(map $_->[1], @$val)` determines the maximum value of the second elements of the arrays in AoA $val. This maximum is then ignored. The second array in `$val` is copied to `@slice` and set to `undef` in `$val`. (`delete` doesn't work on arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print "$key\t $ignored[0]->[0]\t$ignored[0]->[1]";
```

You have an array of arrays, so each element of `@ignored` is an array.  The notation `$ignored[0]` gets to the zeroth element (which is an array), and `->[0]` and `->[1]` retrieves the zeroth and first elements of that array.

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @ignored;
$ignored[0] = [ '3420', '3446', '13', '39', 55 ];
my $key = 'miRNA79 dvex219016 +';

print Dumper \@ignored;
print "\n";

print "$key\t$ignored[0]->[0]\t$ignored[0]->[1]";
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '3420',
            '3446',
            '13',
            '39',
            55
          ]
        ];

miRNA79 dvex219016 +    3420    3446
```

Another option that generates the same output is to `join` all the values with a `\t`:

```
print join "\t", $key, @{ $ignored[0] }[ 0, 1 ];
```

Comment: Perfect, simple and -util- solution. Thanks a lot!